# Symfony plugin: call to undefined function 'enablePlugins'

Tags: plugins, symfony1, undefined

I'm trying to install sfMediaBrowserPlugin ( http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfMediaBrowserPlugin/0_2_01?tab=plugin_readme ).

When running 'symfony plugin:publish-assets', it says that the ProjectConfiguration::enablePlugins() method is undefined.

How could I solve this? Thanks!..

By the way: I have a symfony 1.1.6 project with Propel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As listed on the plugin page, you need at least symfony 1.2.

Comment: Ok.. I must be more attentive. Thank you. :)